# what's the difference between systemctl start nginx and systemctl start nginx.service?

Tags: linux, centos7

what's the difference between "systemctl start nginx" and systemctl start nginx.service? I see them in different tutoriols. there're also others which has *.service.

I'm wondering there'r them same ? does it cause issue if i use them together ?

Answer (score 0):

They are exactly the same, don't worry.